# Adding @2x and @3x pictures without 1x version

Tags: ios, xcode

I've started developing an iOS app, adding pictures in resolution which is ok for standard retina screens. Now I want to add @3x pictures for iphone 6 plus and 7 plus. I don't want to include 1x version for older devices. I've renamed all image files to name@2x but these are not recognized in the project anymore. I was thinking that @2x name modifier will be ignored, but this is not the case. Do I need to explicitely add "@2x" in all places I'm referencing these pictures in the code? Or should I leave standard retina versions without any name change and these will be used anyway as @2x and only use @3x name modifier for higher resolution versions?

Comment: Actually I just needed to add picture files to the project once again after renaming them. After that all code references to original files without 2x and 3x are working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use asset catalogs. See [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_ref-Asset_Catalog_Format/)

Then it's really easy to define 1x, 2x and 3x images by drag&drop. If you load the image in code by name (without scale) it works like a charm. If 1x is missing the next possible image will be used automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can import *pdf-images* or well known as **vector-images** as single vector in *assets*.Hence No need of `1x,2x,3x` seperatly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Blade](https://github.com/jondot/blade)

> Better asset workflow for iOS developers. Generate Xcode image catalogs for iOS / OSX app icons, universal images, and more.

with a definition file like this will generate all the images for you and put it in the right place

```
blades:
- source: store/slice1.png # this image should be the only image, and the biggest image you can use (typically for icons, 1024x1024)
  mount: Project/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset
```